# How do you bind a TextBlock text in the MainWindow to a property in a seperate User Control?

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, mvvm, viewmodel

I'm having a problem with binding across User Controls. I have a Notification bar which is displayed over the entire application, but I want to change its text from within a User Control's View Model using binding. I've looked at many ways of doing it but I haven't been able to get it working.

Each XAML control has no code behind, and in a separate class I am creating a View Model. This is then assigned to the XAML's data context when it is initialized.

Can anyone help with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use some kind of Event system, such as MVVM Light's [Messenger](http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/) or Prism's [EventAggregator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx)

This would allow the `ViewModel` containing the notification message to subscribe and listen to events of type `ShowNotificationEvent`, and when it gets one it can set the value and show the notification.

Any area in the application that wishes to show a notification only has to raise a `ShowNotificationEvent` and pass it the message to display

Comment: Thank you! I've implemented the EventAggregator and have got it working!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the great prism's `EventAggregator` [here is a tutorial how to implement it](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/355473/Prism-EventAggregator-Sample)